# Expressing regular expression in words

Tags: regex

I am trying to express the following regular expression in words. Please not this is not so much a programming regex, as opposed to some CS work I am doing. The regular expression is:

```
(ab + b)* + (ba + b)*
```

The spaces are meaningless and the '+' functions as an 'or'. My answer right now is:

"This regular expression represents every string that does not contain the substring 'aa', and whose last letter is 'b' if the first letter is 'a'"

Is this correct? If so, that last condition I put makes me a bit weary. Is there a way to perhaps simplify the summation?

Thanks guys.

Comment: "The '+' functions as an 'or'." That's not a regular expression.

Comment: It functions as a logical or. The CS book I am reading from uses '+' notation. Not sure how it is not a regular expression. For example if the regex was: "(a + b)", the entire language is just { 'a', 'b' }.

Comment: This regular expression matches an empty string, repetitions of the string `ab`, repetitions of the string `b` and repetitions of the string `ba`.

Comment: Incidentally, when your CS book uses the phrase "regular expression," what it likely means is "an expression in a regular grammar." 99.9% of the time, when someone uses the term "regular expression" or "regex", they're referring to [POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, not sure I agree with @ChristianTernus's reduction.

Assuming these are implicitly anchored, the original, `(ab|b)*|(ba|b)*`, in English, is:

1. a string *entirely* composed of `ab` and `b`, or
2. a string *entirely* composed of `ba` and `b`.

So, for example, `abb` would match as the first kind but not the second, and `bba` would match the second kind but not the first.

Meanwhile, note how neither `abb` nor `bba` would match the reduction, `(ab)*|(ba)*|(b)*`, which actually means,

1. a string *entirely* composed of `ab`, or
2. a string *entirely* composed of `ba`, or
3. a string *entirely* composed of `b`.

---

Actually, the way you Englishified it, I think was already the best! Though, I'd style it like this:

> This regular expression represents a string composed entirely of 'a's and 'b's, with no consecutive 'a's, and whose last character is 'b' if the first character is 'a'.

Nearly identical to what you already wrote.

---

As @ChristianTernus (and @slebetman) point out, the above fails to take into account that the original expression accepts a null string (or even a string without 'a's, which isn't clear from my Englishification), so in fact I believe OP's Englishification was indeed the strongest.

Comment: Agreed. I noticed that also from his deduction. I believe my Englishification (hehe) is correct now too. I was hoping to get it confirmed and to see if it was possible to reduce it.

Comment: I disagree. In one place you assume + is _inclusive_-or, and in another place you assume + is _exclusive_-or.

Comment: @ChristianTernus - I'd like to understand what you mean, but I'm having trouble. Could you explain in a little more detail? I'm not familiar with _formal_ regular expressions (only what I've learned from programming), so it's quite possible I'm mistaken.

Comment: You know what, doing some more analysis, you're right and I'm wrong. :) I'd still phrase it differently, though: your Englishification doesn't match the null string, whereas the original regex would.

Comment: @ChristianTernus - Your quick and humble rescindence shows your strength :-) And yeah, nice catch! You're right about the null string; so in fact OP's original formulation was the strongest.

Comment: Note that the zero-or-more qualifier basically means that pedantically, an empty string would also match.

Comment: @slebetman That might seem pedantic, but when you're wondering why your regex is coming up with _way_ more matches than you think it should, it matters a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

> `(ab + b)* + (ba + b)*`

Translated into common (PCRE) regex, that's

`(ab|b)*|(ba|b)*`

In other words: **a string composed of either zero or more instances of either 'ab' or 'b', or zero or more instances of either 'ba' or 'b'.**

@acheong87's answer is also correct. I like this because it matches more closely the original structure of the regular expression -- it wouldn't be hard to turn this back into the regex from whence it came.

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression that, when reading this regex, that the or implies one or the other. So we either choose (ab|b)* OR (ba|b)*. Then we can only repeat from one. So for example, the string 'abba' is not in the language, but under your simplification, it is.

Comment: Oh I see what you were getting at, but... Does the * notation not allow you to choose again between the OR's? So for example again, (a|b)* you could have the string 'ab' in it. Thanks for the quick reply.